# Way to storage object without rdbms or plain file with Java

Tags: java, caching, static, system, storage

first of all sorry for my English is not my native language.
I have a web form input field and a servlet (**Clustered** Weblogic AS) which receives the contents of this input. I would like to limit the attempts given the same value **without using rdbms or plain text file**, eg

```
// Getting value of form
String input = request.getParameter ("input");

// Attempts object saves the previously set values
if (attempts.check (input)> 3) (
   throw new Exception ();
Else ()
   attempts.setValue (input);
)
```

And I do not decide which is the most efficient way of doing it without using db or plain file.

- Java Cache System
- Static Variable

Another way?

Comment: Yes, I can use session variables.

Answer (score 0):

caching and saving in a static variable will only last as long as the server is running.
once you restart the server - your data is lost. out of the two - a static variable sounds faster. but if persistence is what you need - then you will have to write it to a file\db\nosql-db of some kind.